# If $\alpha_i$ are the roots of $x^n + nax−b = 0$ then show that $\prod_{1< i \le n} (\alpha_1 -\alpha_i)=n(\alpha_1^{n-1}+a)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, roots, quadratics

If $\alpha_i$ are the roots of  $x^n + nax−b = 0$ then I would like to show that $$\prod_{1< i \le n} (\alpha_1 -\alpha_i)=n(\alpha_1^{n-1}+a).$$

The only thing I could think is differentiating $x^n + nax−b = 0.$

What to do after that is the problem.

Comment: sorry its α1 @OlivierOloa

Comment: Hint: Note that $x^n + nax + b = \prod_{1\le i \le n} (x -\alpha_i)$. Now, differentiate both sides, on the RHS you'll get a sum of $n$ polynomials of the form $\prod_{j \neq i} (x - \alpha_j)$, one for each $i$. Now feed in an appropriate value of $x$ into this relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the identity
$$
x^n + nax + b = \prod_{1\le i \le n} (x -\alpha_i)
$$ one has, for $x \neq \alpha_1$,
$$
\frac{x^n + nax + b}{x-\alpha_1} = \prod_{1< i \le n} (x -\alpha_i)
$$ then letting $x \to \alpha_1$, one gets 
$$
n\alpha_1^{n-1}+n a=\prod_{1< i \le n} (\alpha_1 -\alpha_i)
$$ as announced, where we have used
$$
\lim_{x \to \alpha_1}\frac{x^n + nax + b}{x-\alpha_1} =\lim_{x \to \alpha_1}\frac{(x^n + nax + b)-0}{x-\alpha_1} =\lim_{x \to \alpha_1}\frac{f(x)-f(\alpha_1)}{x-\alpha_1}=f'(\alpha_1).
$$